# discord.py - Adding roles issue

Tags: python, discord.py

I was trying to make an reaction menu to give roles, so far its working, but the problem is when I do the command `!lol @[person here]` and react to it, it adds the roles to the author (me) and not the user that I mentioned, please help

My Code is

```
import discord
#import secreto
import asyncio
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

COR =0x690FC3
msg_id = None
msg_user = None

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('BOT ONLINE!')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def lol(ctx, user = discord.Member):
        message = ctx.message
        embed1 =discord.Embed(title=f"Choose {user.name}'s rank", color=COR, description=" - Pineapple\n - Apple\n - Watermellon")
        botmsg = await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed1)
        await client.add_reaction(botmsg, "")
        await client.add_reaction(botmsg, "")
        await client.add_reaction(botmsg, "")
        global msg_id
        msg_id = botmsg.id

        global msg_author
        msg_author = message.author

        global msg_user
        msg_user = user

@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    msg = reaction.message
    if reaction.emoji == "" and msg.id == msg_id: # and user == msg_user:
        role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Bronze")
        await client.add_roles(user, role)
        print("add" + user.name)

    if reaction.emoji == "" and msg.id == msg_id:
        role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Prata")
        await client.add_roles(user, role)
        print("add")

    if reaction.emoji == "" and msg.id == msg_id:
        role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Ouro")
        await client.add_roles(user, role)
        print("add")
```

Answer (score 1):

`user` in `on_reaction_add(reaction, user)` is always the user who reacted to the message. What you need is `mentioned_user = message.mentions[0]` to get the user mentioned in your message and give him the according role.

Comment: Can you please add the code with that, I dont know where to put it, please

Comment: In your code, just everywhere you have `await client.add_roles(user, role)` replace it with `await client.add_roles(message.mentions[0], role)`. Keep in mind this will break if there is noone mentioned in the message being reacted to.

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range